# Simple relative cell referencing in google code

Tags: cell, spreadsheet

I have made this virtual inventory with buttons that copy and paste values to various sheets for different types of reports. The code might not be optimal I am not much of a programmer but I'm trying my best. now I have the same button in multiple places and I want it to copy values in cells relative to the position of the button itself but I am not sure how to reference a cell in a relative manner in the getRange fucntion.

here is the code:

```
function Go() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fiche");
  var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
  var source = ss.getRange ('(rowid-3)(colid)');
  var checkbox = sheet.getRange (3,3);
   var destColumn = ss.getRange ('B10').getValues ();
   
  source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true});

  
    if (checkbox.getValue() == 'vrai' ) {
         
         var source = ss.getRange ('B9');
      
        source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, destColumn), {contentsOnly: true});
        source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2), {contentsOnly: true});
    }
    else {
    
    var nombre = ss.getRange ('D5').getValues() ;
    
        destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, destColumn).setValue(nombre);
        destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(nombre)
    }
```

I want all (B10),(B9), etc. format cells to be replaced with relative cell positons. I have tried with (colID)(rowID) but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the cell coordinate when a button on Spreadsheet is clicked.

### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, when a button on Spreadsheet is clicked, there are no methods for directly retrieving the information where button is clicked.

  - So when you want to use the button on Spreadsheet, if you want to retrieve the information, it is required to prepare each script for each button. But I thought that this might be different from the direction you expect.
- In this answer, in order to retrieve the information where the button is clicked, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns as the workarounds. In these patterns, the event object is used. By this, the information of the button can be retrieved. This is used.

### Pattern 1:

[image]

In this pattern, a cell is used as the button using the simple trigger of OnSelectionChange. When the cell "B3" is used as the button like above image, the script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this script, for example, when you want to use the cell "B3" of "Sheet1" as the button, please set "B3" to `buttonRanges`. And, set `sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1"`. When when you want to use the cell "B3" and "B4" as the button, please set "B3" and "B4" to `buttonRanges`.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const buttonRanges = ["B3"];
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || !buttonRanges.includes(range.getA1Notation())) return;
  
  const row = range.getRow();  // This is the row number.
  const column = range.getColumn();  // This is the column number.
}
```

- In this case, when the cell "B3" is clicked, this script is run. And `row` and `column` are the row and column number of the cell.
- Because the cell is used as the button, you can put the value to the cell.

### Pattern 2:

[image]

In this pattern, a checkbox is used as the button using the OnEdit trigger. When the cell "B3" is used as the button like above image, the script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this script, for example, when you want to use the cell "B3" of "Sheet1" as the button, please set "B3" to `buttonRanges`. And, set `sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1"`. When when you want to use the cell "B3" and "B4" as the button, please set "B3" and "B4" to `buttonRanges`.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const buttonRanges = ["B3"];
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || !buttonRanges.includes(range.getA1Notation()) || !range.isChecked()) return;
  
  const row = range.getRow();  // This is the row number.
  const column = range.getColumn();  // This is the column number.
}
```

- In this case, when the checkbox is checked, the script is run. When the checkbox is unchecked, the script is not run.
- Because the checkbox is used as the button, you cannot see the text in the cell.

### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- Related question

  - [Button change text display every after click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095150/7108653)

    - This question is for achieving the switching button.