Is there a way to ID buttons in Apps Scripts so that I can assign many buttons the same function, but it only executes on the button that was clicked?
Original Question
I am creating a sheet where I need to have several buttons with the same function (add a value of 1 to the column left of it when clicked). I know how to do this by creating the code for one, then duplicating it, changing the cell that has the added value, and assigning it to a different button.
I'm looking for a work-around that will allow the code to identify which button was clicked and add the value of 1 to the corresponding left cell. Is that possible?
This is the current code I'm running for one of my buttons, in case it is helpful or you have feedback on it:
function add1Row3
() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var cellRange = sheet.getRange("B3");

  var currentValue = cellRange.getValue();

  var newValue = currentValue + 1; 

  cellRange.setValue(newValue);

}

I also tried changing to checkboxes and using this code:
function onEdit (e) {
  if (!e) throw "Do not run from Editor";
  increment (e);
}

function increment(e) {
const source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const r = e.range();

if (src.getName () != "Checkbox" || r.columnStart !=3) return;

let out;
if (r.columnStart == 3) {
  out = r.offset (0,-1);
  out.setValue(out.getValue()+1)
} 

r.setValue("FALSE")

}

Problems
I thought that would let any checkbox that was checked in column C increase the value of the corresponding number in column B by 1 and then reset the checkbox. However, nothing happens when I check the box.
I also tried the code @TheMaster gave me, but it also does nothing when the checkbox is checked.

Unfortunately that is not possible. A script assigned to an Image is not context-aware of the image's location relative to the cell containing it. However, there is a feature request for related capabilities under Google's issue tracker. Consider upvoting the issue to bring more attention to it.

Would it be possible then if I removed the image and just used the cell location?

There is no way to do that with buttons currently (November 2024). You can however use with checkboxes to a similar effect. See my checkboxButtons_ script for sample code.

Checkboxes it is then. Still working on exact code.

As a workaround, when a cell or an image in the cell is used as a button, these approaches might be useful. "Workaround 3" of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63108140, or https://stackoverflow.com/a/64618171/7108653 or https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/07/27/switching-buttons-for-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/

The better way is just to use a checkbox instead and add it to a edit trigger.
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
const onEdit = (e) => {
  const editedCell = e.range;
  if (
    editedCell.isChecked() &&
    editedCell.getSheet().getName() === 'Sheet1' &&
    /*c1-c15*/ /^c(([1-9])|(1[0-5]))$/i.test(editedCell.getA1Notation())
  ) {
    const leftCell = editedCell.offset(0, -1);
    leftCell.setValue(Number(leftCell.getValue()) + 1);
    editedCell.unCheck();
  }
};

However, it is possible to create multiple functions and attach different images to each function programmatically.
It is also possible to getAnchorCell and get the offset:
const setPlusOne = () => {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getImages().forEach((img) => {
    const anchorCell = img.getAnchorCell();
    if (/*b1-b15*/ /^b(([1-9])|(1[0-5]))$/i.test(anchorCell.getA1Notation())) {
      const leftCell = anchorCell.offset(0, -1);
      leftCell.setValue(Number(leftCell.getValue()) + 1);
    }
  });
};


Thank you for the specific code, but the code isn't working for me, and I can't figure out why? I'm using the first code you gave with the checkboxes. I have checkboxes in column C and values in Column B. When I click on any of the checkboxes, nothing happens.

@JanaLeeMoses if sheet name isn't Sheet1, change it in code or your sheet
