# Button who swap color on click

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets and i was trying to make a button who swap between red and green when we click on it, unfortunately, all the information i find to help me do that seems to work only with Uiapp but Uiapp is not available anymore and i was trying to find any equivalent with Htmlservice but i don't find any, tbh i didn't thought swap color on a button with a click would have been that complicated. If someone have any help to give me like a script to add in the button i'm interested thanks you (Btw sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Click the cell where you want a button
Insert Drawing
Select Shapes
Select Rectangle
Click Fill Color
Click Transparent
Save

You will get the button in the sheet
Place it in any cell
Make the cell size equal to the rectangle
Assign the script function to the drawing

```
function clicked() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range=sht.getRange("G8");
  var c1=range.getBackgrounds();
  if (c1=="#ff9900"){
    range.setBackground("#ffff00");
  } else {
    range.setBackground("#ff9900");
  }
}
//
//
```

Sample Sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8sp9oSNg221uJ0wHtF3UvxCKTEzyApknchvBE-MibQ/edit#gid=0

But, this does not change the color of the button - but, changes the background of the cell. It appears as if the color of the button is changing.