# How do I create a button that changes text and color on click in Google Sheets App Scripts / Drawing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

I have a sheet of statistics based on a list of players marked as either active or inactive. I currently have a check box on my sheet to toggle between active and inactive players; however, I'd like to update that to a button that when clicked, does the toggling in the background.

Upon doing so, I want the button to say "Show Active Only" (in green) when all players are listed and then once clicked, change to say "Show All Players" (in red).

I have the following code set up for my toggling button but do not know how to make it change upon clicking.

```
function ActiveOnly() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2');
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (value == true) {
    range.setValue(false);
  } else if (value == false) {
    range.setValue(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I have a button with the text "Show Active Players". When the button is clicked, I would like it to say "Show All Players". When clicked again, go back to "Show Active Players."

In addition, I am wondering if it can be one color (green) and change color (red) when clicked. Then when clicked again, go back to green.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe create a transparent button with a white or black frame. Then change the cell color and text underneath with your script?

Comment: Wish there was a better way but this is a good work around. Thank you.